# Change font color to session variable when displayed using razor syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model-view-controller

I have a session variable that I am appending to a string in the layout page of an MVC application.

```
<p class="text-primary text-strong">Logged in as: @Session["DisplayName"]</p>
```

I would like the "Logged in as:" to display in black and the "@Session["DisplayName"]" to be blue. Is it possible to format razor syntax like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't really have anything to do with razor. Just some simple CSS will do the trick.

```
<style type="text/css">    
   .blueText {
      color: #0000FF;
   } 
</style>

<p class="text-primary text-strong">
   Logged in as: <span class="blueText">@Session["DisplayName"]</span>
</p>
```